# Compilation error on the DEBUG identifier in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to build a static C++ library using Xcode. I get a build error on the `DEBUG` identifier in enum below, not sure why that is happening. I can compile it by using Clang++ from a terminal. Why does the compilation fail in Xcode?

**Error:**

```
Parse Issue
temp_1.h:9:5: Expected identifier
```

**temp_1.h**

```
enum LogLevel {

    DONT_PRINT = 0,
    SPEW       = 1,
    DEBUG     = 2,
    INFO       = 3,
    WARNING    = 4,
    ERROR      = 5,
    FATAL      = 6,
    INVALID                     = 7,
    NO_EXIT_ON_ERROR            = 8,
    MANDATORY                   = 9
};

class temp_1 {    
 public:
    temp_1();
    int get_var();
    void set_var(int _var);

 private:
    int var;    
};
```

**temp_1.cpp:**

```
#include "temp_1.h"

temp_1::temp_1() {        
    var = DEBUG;
}    
int temp_1::get_var() {
    return var;
}    
void temp_1::set_var(int _var) {    
    var = _var;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of build environments define the preprocessor macro `DEBUG` when the code is compiled in debug mode, so that you can write

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// do something in debugging mode only
#endif
```

It looks like in your Xcode build, `DEBUG` is defined to something that isn't an identifier, perhaps `DEBUG=1` or `DEBUG=`. Therefore your code after preprocessing looks like `SPEW = 1, 1 = 2,` or `SPEW = 1, = 2,`.

Avoid using the identifier `DEBUG` in your code. In C, you would typically put a prefix before these identifiers: `LOG_LEVEL_DONT_PRINT`, `LOG_LEVEL_SPEW`, `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG`, etc. In C++, namespaces mostly make such prefixes unnecessary and undiomatic. Nonetheless, avoid all-uppercase `DEBUG`. You could name just this identifier differently, or use `Spew`, `Debug`, etc. and reserve all-caps to the preprocessor.

If you can't avoid using the identifier `DEBUG`, then you can allow the program to build by making sure that your build environment never defines it as a processor macro. If you want to have your cake and eat it, you can do better: ensure that **either `DEBUG` is undefined or it is defined to `DEBUG`** (i.e. nothing or `-UDEBUG`, or `-DDEBUG=DEBUG` on a compiler command line). When a preprocessor macro expands to itself, this passes the identifier unchanged to the next stage of the compiler (so `DEBUG` will act normally as an identifier), but blocks in a conditional compilation directive `#ifdef DEBUG` … `#endif` will be compiled.

Comment: Thanks, I agree to your comment, unfortunately above snapshot is from a pre-existing helper library and used across multiple projects so I doubt I will get to modify it

Comment: @Jim In that case I think your best bet is to define DEBUG=DEBUG rather than DEBUG=1 or some such, see my edit.

Comment: in "Build Settings" where preprocessing macros are defined, I found DEBUG=1 that you mentioned above, removing this works

Comment: your suggestion makes more sense, will try that out. thanks for helping out!